# Abrir aplicativo do Google por um link web no Android

Tags: html, android, html5

como abrir o app do gplus via html, redes sociais tipo o facebook, é fb:// o instagram:// e o google+ nao consigo encontrar, para o ios usa gplus:// porem nao da certo de abrir o app android

Comment: vc quer abrir via android (app) ou via html?

Comment: vou abrir via webview html